# Bigquery returns (500) Error with query

Tags: google-bigquery

we have been using the following query for months and now suddenly (within the last hour) BigQuery started returning "Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/877311797081/queries: (500) Unexpected. Please try again"

```
SELECT DATE(SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(sdate+(-4*3600))) AS d, 0 as range, 
       SUM(IF(type=0,1,0)) as looks, SUM(IF(type=1,1,0)) as books,
       SUM(IF(type=1,nights,0)) AS nights, SUM(base_total*currencies.USD) as totals,
       SUM(base_rate*currencies.USD*IF(type=1,nights,0)) as adr, 
FROM [reztrack.201307] 
WHERE act=157 AND 
      (( ((sdate+(-4*3600)) >= 1372636800 AND (sdate+(-4*3600))<= 1375228799) )) 
GROUP BY d,range 
ORDER BY range, d ASC
```

I Checked our account to make sure there were no overages on quota limits or billing issues. Trying several other queries, even basic ones seem to net the same result.

Comment: Seems that the exact same query is now working again, no changes made by me to the code. Happy it is working again, but would love hear any thoughts on what the potential issue was if at all possible... happy to provide any additional data that might help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We released a new version of BigQuery this morning, it had a bug affecting tables that had been truncated, so we rolled it back. Please let us know if you see any further issues.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Jordan! I am not seeing any of the previous issues at this time.